# Confusion regarding DNS query vs HOSTS file

Tags: networking, dns, hosts-file

With the subject, I have windows/linux machine and In which installed virtualbox and setup *192.168.11.19* ip and entry *www.abc.com* in hosts file. We have setup DNS server/filter on network and setup DNS on every machine.

Now problem is that, Why DNS query to DNS server of *www.abc.com*,because which already resolved using hosts file. What order of HOSTS file and DNS server ?

Comment: Does the query occur only when navigating from the VM, or also from the host?

Comment: @user2313067 Query from hosts

Answer (score 0):

### Q.   Why DNS query to DNS server of www.abc.com,because which already resolved using hosts file.

### A. Your computer should use the hosts file first and not do a lookup.

Just like how you seem to want it do be doing.  This saves bandwidth and useless queries etc...

### Testing:

If you pick a new ip address (or flush the dns cache) and test it you should see.

Here is an example that mixes up Free Software Foundation and Google's addresses.

We can get the ip for www.fsf.org:

```
nslookup fsf.org
```

Gives the answer:

server:208.67.222.222

```
nslookup 8.8.8.8
```

name = google-public-dns-a.google.com

#### 1) Put the incorrect record in the hosts file.

```
8.8.8.8 www.fsf.org
```

in the hosts file ( /etc/hosts possibly).

This is google's ip address, for the free software foundation.org name.

#### 2) restart the computer or the networking service.

#### 3) `ping www.fsf.org`

You should see that your computer pings 8.8.8.8, which is google.  If it pinged 208.67.222.222, you would know it was using dns.

I just did the test on my computer.

Of course the point of dns is that it is scalable so that you don't have to write that down anymore and it gets updated automatically, but you may find the hosts file useful for internal network use or as shorthand external addresses.

Cheers.

Comment: Checked, Hosts entry correct and If i try to nslookup then get " Server:  UnKnown
Address:  192.168.1.249

Name:    www.abc.com.corp.domain.com
Addresses:  192.168.1.249
   192.168.1.249 
why?

Comment: Can you see what your dns address is and if you can ping it?

Comment: yes and 192.168.1.249 my DNS server and setup only this in system for internet, It's working fine

Comment: CAn you check the the computer hostname is a fully qulified domain name:  computer.corpdomain.com?  (not just "computer").                     What do you get from  nslookup 192.168.1.249?                              Can you make a new hosts entry and ping the name?  Something new.  The hosts file should work regardless of dns or not.

Comment: 1) Now system in domain but win server not connected 2) nslookup response  UnKnown can't find ip(nxfilter). 3) problem is not a domain name resolve etc. but why www.abc.com(192.168.11.19) is try to resolve on nxfilter(192.168.1.249)? on system,  www.abc.com is working fine !!

Comment: Just to be clear, is abc.com an external ip address or internal?  I was assuming it was external.  Your hosts file should work fine with or without dns.

Comment: Have you tried to ping the entry in the hosts file?   nslookup and dig will always ask the dns server because they are dns tools.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40607/discussion-between-bloodyel-and-ravi-g).